# Same scale on X and Y axis in R curve

Tags: r, plot

When I use R's `curve()` function, is there a way to force it to use the same scale on the X and the Y axis?

For example, consider this R code

```
mean <- 5
variance <- 0.05
curve(exp((((x - mean) / variance)^2) * -0.5), mean - 2, mean + 2)
```

This will give me this plot:

[image: Plot for curve]

As you can see, the X axis and the Y axis use different scales. How can I fix this?

Note: I know I can manually specify the range of the Y axis (via `ylim=`) but I'd rather not use this (as this would require adopting it whenever the function changes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `asp` plotting parameter, for aspect ratio. Set `asp = 1` in the call to `curve()`:

```
mean <- 5
variance <- 0.05
curve(exp((((x - mean) / variance)^2) * -0.5), mean - 2, mean + 2, asp = 1)
```

That will do it.

It is not quite perfect if you want `xlim == ylim` or if you want better labelling of the axes, but `asp` gets the same scale on both axes.